# How does phoneGap (Cordova) work internally, iOS specific

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have started developing html applications for mutliple platforms. I recently heard about Cordova 2.0(PhoneGap) and ever since I have been curious to know how the bridge works.
After lot of code walking, i saw that the Exec.js is the code where call from JS -> Native happens

```
execXhr = execXhr || new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Changeing this to a GET will make the XHR reach the URIProtocol on 4.2.
        // For some reason it still doesn't work though...
        execXhr.open('HEAD', "file:///!gap_exec", true);
        execXhr.setRequestHeader('vc', cordova.iOSVCAddr);
        if (shouldBundleCommandJson()) {
            execXhr.setRequestHeader('cmds', nativecomm());
        }
        execXhr.send(null);
    } else {
        execIframe = execIframe || createExecIframe();
        execIframe.src = "gap://ready";
```

But want to understand how that works, what is the concept here, what does file:///!gap_exec or gap://ready do? and how does the call propgate to the lower layers (native code layers)

thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is easy:

There is a webview. This displays your app.  The webview will handle all navigation events.

If the browser navigates to:

```
file:///!gap_exec
```

or

```
gap://
```

the webview will cancel the navigation. Everything behind these strings is re-used as an identifier, to get the concrete plugin/plugin-method and parameter:

pseudo-url example:

```
gap://echoplugin/echothistext?Hello World
```

This will cause phonegap to look for an `echoplugin` and call the `echothistext` method to send the text `"Hello World"` to the (native) plugin.

**update**

The way back from native to javascript is (or may be) loading a `javascript:` url into the webview.

The concrete implementation is a little bit more complex, because the javascript has to send a callback-id to native code. There could be more than one native call are running at the same time. But in fact this is no magic at all. Just a number to get the correct JSON to the right javascript-callback.

There are different ways to communicate between the platform and javascript. For Android there are three or four different bridges.

Comment: I figured this out long time back. But your answer is correct. Thanks

Comment: could you update your response, if you're still following cordova? It looks like exec injects an iframe with src="gap://ready" and that's the only js... then CDVViewController.m intercepts all requests to 'gap' with shouldStartLoadWithRequest then CDVCommandQueue.m uses stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to grab the js command queue.

Comment: @Christian Kuetbach: You said like "There could be more than one native call are running at the same time". My situation is exactly the same. I need to call one native plugin method more than once simultaneously. I also want to pass a response from native plugin (as plugin result using callback ID) for each plugin call from JavaScript. I am not sure how does Cordova behave in this context. I have asked a separate question for this purpose. If possible, could you please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/q/32139534/2035845.

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to figure this out in more detail, too. Basically there are 2 Methods on the iOS side that can help ...

- [- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) and
- [- stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

From the sources it seems cordova sends a "READY" message using webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:... and then picks up results with the second message, but I am not sure.

[Cordova Sources iOSExec](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-js.git;a=blob;f=lib/ios/exec.js;h=1c2c1f2cf7819ea9ae6cb576ba78699f2a99e7cf;hb=24d65ab645742e8360c3dd16d7a36411cc3383e0)

There is much to learn there.

Comment: I believe you're right, and seeing your answer saved me from going down the wrong rabbit hole for too many more hours. Check out my response to @Christian-kuetbach above for a 10,000 ft perspective