# iOS Cordova: Does Cordova create multiple instances of an objective-C plugin when called more than once?

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins

I am working on a iOS hybrid application based on Cordova. We have a Objective-C plugin file (MyPlugin.h and MyPlugin.m) which is typically a subclass of CDVPlugin.

We call the objective-C plugin from a JavaScript file like below.

```
cordova.exec(success, error, "MyPlugin", "callNativeActivity", args);
```

Here, **success-** success callback function,
**error-** error callback function
and **args-** array of arguments.

Below is the native plugin method signature.

```
-(void)callNativeActivity:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)cdvCommand;
```

We are initiating a NSURLConnection task asynchronously inside the plugin class. So, it will wait for the response to come from web server. After the response comes, we send it back to JavaScript as a CDVPluginResult object.

```
if (isSuccess) {

        CDVPluginResult *result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDictionary:jsonPayload];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:cdvCommand.callbackId];

}else{            
        CDVPluginResult *result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsDictionary:jsonPayload];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:cdvCommand.callbackId];
}
```

There are few cases, wherein we need to call the plugin more than once simultaneously from JavaScript (without waiting for the response from plugin class).

**How does Cordova handles if we call it multiple times. Will it mess up with the response which I send back to JavaScript? I know that Cordova has distinct callback ID for sending the plugin result. But, is there any chance of my response being sent to wrong instance?**

Hope my question is clear!! Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From the specs [Plugin Initialization and Lifetime](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins):

> One instance of a plugin object is created for the life of each
>   UIWebView. Plugins are ordinarily instantiated when first referenced
>   by a call from JavaScript. Otherwise they can be instantiated by
>   setting a param named onload to true in the config.xml file.

This means, there is only one instance of a plugin per CordovaApp/WebView.

The callbacks are handled properly, by the ID.

It works *like* this (not sure about the real implementation):

- Each time you call `cordova.exec(...)` a callback-ID is generated.
- The application maps to callback[ID]= {success, error}
- Your native code calls onSuccess(ID) and the success will be called
- After calling onSuccess or onError, the callback[ID] is set to null

In the real world, there can also be some kind of progress listeners, but they should also work with the correct callback-ID.

Comment: Thanks for adding lot of good information!! As you said, there'll be only one instance of a plugin. Which means that, when I invoke the plugin more than once, the same plugin method (in my case, it's callNativeActivity:) will be called every time (with different callback ID).  So, what if I am doing some time taking operations or  calculation inside the plugin method. Will it be overridden when the next time plugin is invoked from JavaScript? Hope I am clear about my doubt.

Comment: I don't get you problem. If you write a plugin yourself, it needs to be some kind of Threadsafe. Don't store variables in the plugin instance, which are not shared over all requests. You will need to store everything in the context of the callback-ID.